# How to prevent voltage spikes when motor is turned off

Tags: voltage, brushless-dc-motor, tvs, inductive, spike

I have a schematics as shown below. The power source is a benchtop power supply which supplies a constant 24V power. Motor is controlled with ESC.

When running the motor and then turning it off I can see that voltage rises significantly (more than 35V). I understand that this should be because of the motor which is an inductive load. So when ESC switches motor off the magnetic field collapses which generates a temporary voltage across the inductive load which basically acts as a series connected battery.

How would I handle this so there is no voltage swing when motor turns off? Would a flyback diode over the power input rails help? Or should I add a clamping device like a TVS diode between the rails?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you're not regenerating during deceleration? If so you may need to add voltage sensing to switch in a dummy load on the 24 V supply to absorb the voltage.

Comment: Yes, this might be possibility as well. Is the dummy option only viable solution? I would like the solution to be as simple as possible. Wouldn't TVS diode across rails help in this solution? It is okay if the voltage rises 2-3V, that's acceptable.

Comment: You'd need to work out how much energy you have to dissipate in the worst case and design around that. Perhaps a diode on the positive supply is all that is required to protect the 24 V supply but will the ESC itself tolerate the high voltage?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a H bridge type circuit in your ESC then the surge might be due to not having enough bulk capacitance across the 24 volt power so that the excess energy from motor deceleration or back emf (less likely) can be absorbed into the capacitor. It's common practice. See the picture below: -

[image]

In red is the bulk capacitor. The purple arrows and diodes show a route of the current when the motor is free running due to all the MOSFETs being off. If there is sufficient torque on the motor due to the load, it will attempt to back-feed the power supply and bulk capacitor. The bulk capacitor is the first line of defense in that it won't prevent a small rise in bus voltage (\$V_{DD}\$) but can overcome most difficulties in pushing rotational energy back onto the bus.

However, this may not be sufficient and a braking resistor might be considered to absorb that energy into heat. This means bulk capacitor plus braking resistor. If all else fails and the bus voltage does rise over-excessively then a zener clamp or TVS might be required.

Comment: I'm not sure which type of ESC it is, but it already has some capacitors on it. Also, my first instinct was also to provide more capacitance, so I tried adding 1000uF, but it seemed to have no effect what so ever.

Answer (score 0):

Provided it is not regenerative braking (it seems to me that it was excluded), then is the fluxed inductance of the motor when switched off.
Without information on the inductance value and rated current, as well as length of wires, and switch off time, besides the suggested TVS, I may suggest in addition a RC snubber right across the motor terminals.